# Why can't I edit an SVN commit message?

Tags: version-control, svn

I'm using SVN. Sometimes I miss something when I write a commit message. But once it's been committed, it cannot be reverted, and even I can't edit the message. Why they didn't put the edit function in it?

Comment: Reminds me of the story of [Dave.cpp](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Davecpp.aspx) on thedailtywtf

Comment: Just use *git*, it allows to merge commits, edit messages and do whatever else you like with your history.

Comment: Or if you can't, then use `git-svn` and noone will be the wiser.

Comment: @Matthew: how on earth with git-svn enable you to change the history in a history-editing-disabled svn repo?

Comment: @gbjbaanb: It wouldn't, if you've already pushed up to the SVN server. But if you've only commited locally, you can still change the commit message before pushing it into the live repo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the SVN FAQ, [you can if the repository administrator has enabled it or if you have local administrative access to the repository](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg).

However, doing this is probably a bad idea. You are, in effect, changing history. One of the points of version control is to maintain a history and audit trail for the project. Allowing arbitrary changes to the history defeats the audit trail. Instead, I would recommend that you perform smaller commits, writing concise yet explicit commit messages, and improving your personal workflow to prevent these errors.

Comment: See: git. Where changing history is part of many normal workflows. Changing *public* history is still bad though. Unfortunately, SVN has no concept of 'private' history; everything is on the server, always.

Comment: @Matthew Even in git, changing history at any point is, in my opinion, a terrible idea. The history is supposed to serve as an audit trail and should never be changed by anyone at any point ever for any reason.

Comment: So have an audit trail for the commit message, because usually the purposes of changing the commit message is to make it *easier* to follow the history of the project.

Comment: @Thomas, personally at least, I don't think I'd ever be able to follow a log visualisation with lots of merge commits when you have even a half dozen devs on a single project. `rebase` at the least is a necessity in my mind. Also, squashing commits (lots of tiny save points while tweaking new functionality), splitting commits, cherry-picking in some edge cases (depending on how the branch structure is set up), adding some extra stuff to the last commit you did because you forgot something. All incredibly useful in my mind. Again though, changing public history is a big no-no, always.

Comment: @Matthew Changing any commit message, even in a non-public commit, destroys the auditing capability. In a DCVS, I not only want to audit the main branches that everyone is pushing to, but I want to be able to audit each individual developer if the need arises. If a developer can change their own history, how can I audit them?

Comment: @Thomas: that approach runs the risk of people going outside the VCS to avoid scrutiny about work they're not confident about yet. It's better to give the developers some leeway in structuring their private history, as long as the public history is known (who wrote what line of code, when did it become part of the main build).

Comment: Suppose I discover that a commit message I entered a month ago is misleading, confusing, and downright *wrong*. Shouldn't I be able to added a correcting notation that will be seen by everyone who sees the incorrect message? (I agree the original message should be easily available unmodified and the change itself should be tracked and timestamped. But I disagree that this constitutes "changing history".)

Comment: @Joeri That's nothing to be worried about. If you work in a place where that's an issue, that's a sign of cultural problems. I've checked in some pretty bad trial code (messy, poorly performing, etc) to my private repositories or branches just so there would be an audit trail and history record. It shows what I was trying to do - perhaps someone else could learn from my mistakes, or even improve upon them. In my opinion, when working on a team project, there is no private code - everything should always be visible to anyone who wants to see it.

Comment: @David You should be disiplined enough to not let that happen. If you aren't, that should be a point to address on your continuous improvement and personal development strategy.

Comment: That is just a bizarre thing to say. I hope you simply misread my comment.

Comment: @David No, I read it right. You need to take care to ensure the quality and accuracy of your commit log messages, just as much as your requirements specs, your design docs, your code, and your tests. Confusing is one thing (your name is attached - you can be found and questions can be asked), but wrong or missing information in a commit message is unacceptable.

Comment: Wrong information is unacceptable, therefore people must not be permitted to correct or clarify that information, as that would hide their malfeasance. Wow. Just wow.

Comment: @David No, the wrong information shouldn't be added in the first place. If it is, you are doing something wrong and that something needs to be corrected. A commit log is very much a formal document where accuracy and completeness is required. It all comes back to maintaining the integrity, authenticity, and non-repudiation of the history trail. Allowing anyone to make changes destroys that, therefore no one should be allowed to make changes.

Comment: You are honestly begin to look like a self-parody. "It has to be correct, therefore it must never be corrected."

Comment: @David It has to be entered correctly from the moment it is submitted. There should be no factual or content errors in a commit log. If there are, you are doing it wrong and need to analyze and correct the problem. It is, after all, a formal record.

Comment: I agree with that, but I don't see how that's even remotely responsive to my argument or how that defends your position.

Comment: @David My position is that a (1) the commit log is a formal record that needs to be valid at all points in time for the purpose of auditing (including in non-public branches or repositories), (2) a disciplined engineer should care enough about the commit log that there are no factual errors that require changes, and (3) making any changes to history, including appends, is in fact changing history (which is a violation of point 1).

Comment: 1) I agree. 2) I agree. 3) I disagree. If the append is securely tagged with the time it was made, it is not changing history. Further, such a tagged append is vastly superior to incorrect or misleading commit messages. And mistakes actually do happen, despite people's best efforts to avoid them. Mitigating the damage of an already-made mistake does not in any way detract from efforts to avoid making mistakes in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas I'm going to disagree with you here. It seems a defendable point to suggest that the commit comment should always best represent the change. Ultimately, you're placing historical accuracy of the entry above accurately representing the change. If you want a log for auditing purposes, okay. Being able to not point out errors in commit messages or protect against others basing decisions on incorrect commit messages is just asking for trouble.

Comment: You don't always need audit trails. Actually, most of the time you don't.

Answer (score 5):

> Essentially you have to have admin rights (directly or indirectly) to the repository to
>   do this. You can either configure the repository to allow all users to do this, or you
>   can modify the log message directly on the server.
>
> Check the SVN [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html) here.
>
> > Log messages are kept in the repository as properties attached to
> >     each revision. By default, the log message property (svn:log) cannot
> >     be edited once it is committed. That is because changes to revision
> >     properties (of which svn:log is one) cause the property's previous
> >     value to be permanently discarded, and Subversion tries to prevent you
> >     from doing this accidentally. However, there are a couple of ways to
> >     get Subversion to change a revision property.
> >
> > The first way is for the repository administrator to enable
> >     revision property modifications. This is done by creating a hook
> >     called "pre-revprop-change" (see this section in the Subversion book
> >     for more details about how to do this). The "pre-revprop-change" hook
> >     has access to the old log message before it is changed, so it can
> >     preserve it in some way (for example, by sending an email). Once
> >     revision property modifications are enabled, you can change a
> >     revision's log message by passing the --revprop switch to svn propedit
> >     or svn propset, like either one of these:
> >
> > ```
> > $svn propedit -r N --revprop svn:log URL 
> > $svn propset -r N --revprop svn:log "new log message" URL
> > ```
> >
> > where N is the revision number whose log message you wish to
> >     change, and URL is the location of the repository. If you run this
> >     command from within a working copy, you can leave off the URL.
> >
> > The second way of changing a log message is to use svnadmin
> >     setlog. This must be done by referring to the repository's location on
> >     the filesystem. You cannot modify a remote repository using this
> >     command.
> >
> > ```
> > $ svnadmin setlog REPOS_PATH -r N FILE
> > ```
> >
> > where REPOS_PATH is the repository location, N is the revision
> >     number whose log message you wish to change, and FILE is a file
> >     containing the new log message. If the "pre-revprop-change" hook is
> >     not in place (or you want to bypass the hook script for some reason),
> >     you can also use the --bypass-hooks option. However, if you decide to
> >     use this option, be very careful. You may be bypassing such things as
> >     email notifications of the change, or backup systems that keep track
> >     of revision properties.

Answer from [Kamil Kisiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15061/kamil-kisiel) in response to [a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion/304390#304390).

Comment: When you copy paste an answer from stackoverflow, you should at least mark it as a quote and give credit to the OP (Kamil Kisiel in this case). Link to the original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion Please edit your answer or I am going to downvote you.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's a [*centralized* version control system](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Distributed_revision_control#Distributed_vs._centralized) - As soon as you commit a change (and your commit message is by convention bound to the commit), everybody who has read access to the repository can see that information. **It is a bad idea to change information after it has been disseminated**, because people end up with a different opinion of "reality."

Distributed version control systems like Git alleviate this problem by making sure that the act of making information available to others is atomic and without any additional information like commit messages. But the same principle applies here: You are discouraged from changing things locally which you have already made available to others.

Comment: They could allow multiple versions of the commit message...

Comment: @l0b0 isn’t it objectively worse to continue to disseminate information which is false, misleading, or prone to do damage? Record keeping does not require enshrining bad data.

Comment: @user179700: You're right. There is a fundamentally flawed design assumption in all VCSes I've ever seen: A commit has one commit message, which is immutable. As Alex says, we should "allow multiple versions of the commit message".

Comment: @l0b0 I’m finding this question interesting the more I consider it. My first reaction was along the lines of, just write more carefully. The current practice seems to hamstring the process. I too wonder if any other systems implement a more robust practice. Time for another question methinks. +1

Comment: @user179700: I'm currently hoping to write up a script which allows you to change a commit message, but only by adding a (timestamped) additional string.  That lets you correct mistakes while preserving audit trail.